# Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, digital-ocean

I am getting this error with Laravel 9. I have PHP 8.1.7 installed.

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

I can see other have asked the question, but none of the solutions seem to be working.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple PHP versions. Type `php -v` in the same terminal where you use composer.

Comment: /usr/local/bin# php -v
PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2022 08:12:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

uninstalled and reinstalled Laravel (laravel 9) still same issue

Comment: When is this issue occuring while `composer install`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your environment? How are you accessing composer?

Comment: You can comment checking php version in vendor/composer/ platform-check file and replace it by a False condition like if (1==2)

Answer (score 58):

#### Tips

Add these lines in the *composer.json* file:

```
{
    "config": {

        "platform-check": false
    }
}
```

Or set the version:

```
{
    "config": {

        "platform": {
            "php": "7.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 17):

If you install PHP Composer globally, just run `composer global update`. It will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Running Valet Windows commands on php 8.1 works, but not 7.4 because a dependency of valet's dependency required 8.1. This answer solved my problem.

Comment: Please provide it as text as well. The screenshot is also nearly unreadable. Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thingt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75080139/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen no need to show your reputation here. The screenshot is perfectly readable and clearly states what is needed here

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and it was because I configured a version of PHP 8.1 on the command-line while I kept the PHP module at 8.0.

So PHP_VERSION_ID gave me 80020, while php -v gave me 8.1.7.

It reminded me to reconfigure the PHP Module to PHP version 8.1:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0

sudo a2enmod php8.1

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And then everything worked like intended.

Reference:

- [phpinfo() and php -v shows different version of PHP](https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php)

Comment: I just post this [link](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-php-on-debian-11/) additionally. I had to install php 8.1 on debian server and I chose it with $sudo update-alternatives --config php. Then everything worked properly

Answer (score 8):

Don't change anything in your application. In your shared hosting, go to [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) and find/search for *Multi PHP Manager*. Select your domain or sub domain (whatever you are working with). from the dropdown list. Select *PHP 8.1* and <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

[image]

Now find/search *PHP Selector* and for *Current PHP Version*, select 8.1.

[image]

In the same window, go to *Extensions* and enable *pdo_mysql*.

[image]

You are good to go.

Comment: Best answer out here

Answer (score 7):

If [eril's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73576106/1333160) did not help you by disabling old PHP version,

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

use `composer -vvv about` to check that composer uses the correct version of PHP:

```
composer -vvv about 2>&1 | grep "PHP"
```

If **composer about** already shows a correct version of PHP, then check to see the real PHP binary path that Composer is using by putting `PHP_BINARY` inside `vendor/composer/platform_check.php` like this:

```
if (!(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80100)) {
    $issues[] = 'You are running ' . PHP_VERSION . ' located at: ' . PHP_BINARY;
}
```

In my case, an old version of **php-fpm** was enabled.

```
a2disconf php8.0-fpm
a2enconf php8.1-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 4):

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

I faced the same problem.

Just go to [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel). Then PHP Selector and finally, change the PHP version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"

I had this same issue while I downgraded my PHP to v7.4 from 8.1. I somehow messed up with php7.4-fpm mod.

However, when I again tried to upgrade my PHP v8.1 PHP Composer started to complain about that error.
I simply removed my both PHP versions that's 7.4 and 8.1 and reinstalled only 8.1, which fixed my issue.

To remove it, here are the steps I followed....

```
sudo apt-get purge php8.*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php8.1
and then finally,

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your *composer.json* file and check where the 'require' block says 'php'. It has an expression that can put a constraint on the PHP version or version range that is allowed for all of your projects' dependencies.

A good value would be to use the one below. Change it and run `composer update` afterwards.

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0|^8.1",
```

Contrary to the *composer.json*, which Laravel 9 ships with:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
```

(see the [Laravel 9 *composer.json*](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/composer.json) file in the official repository)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, everything is fine:

- *composer.json* is fine
- PHP 8.1 is installed
- I am using [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). I restart nginx, but I found that my **configuration** is wrong. It looks like this:

  ```
  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
  }
  ```

  So the correct configuration is:

  ```
  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply using Git to version your Composer dependencies for a deployment, consider the `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag.

- For more information, see *Options* at https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i

  ```bash
  composer update --dry-run --ignore-platform-reqs
  ```

  > **`--ignore-platform-reqs`**: ignore all platform requirements (php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-*) and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these. See also the platform config option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on an [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) server, it's likely the *php-fpm8.1* is not active.

Try to:

```
sudo systemctl status php-fpm8.1.service
```

It depends on the status of the *php-fpm* version. You can act, and if it's stopped, you may want to do the following:

```
sudo systemctl enable php-fpm8.1.service
sudo systemctl start php-fpm8.1.service
```

Then double check the status, and if it's active. you’re good to go.

**Note**: This applies to any *php-fpm* version, not just 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue.

- I added the line `phpversion()` and found that the version was different from what was set for my [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) installation.
- I enabled the `php8.1-fpm` with this command:

  ```
  sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
  ```
- After restarting Apache, I got it working.

Answer (score -1):

If you use [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), check that the PHP version of your XAMPP is the correct one (the same one you have on your computer). Otherwise, download and install the correct version of XAMPP.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the process of upgrading Laravel versions and you switch to the version which requires PHP 8 (8 or 9; I can’t remember).
And you also switch PHP versions, you need to restart your

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score -2):

It's just until I find how to solve it, but it's working.
So that's what I've done :

- download php 8.1.9 (nts)
- extract it in *bin/php/*  (I use Laragon)
- move php 7.14.19 in a new folder (just for preventing)
- and rename my php 8 folder to php 7 folder name
- it's still working

Just find the php folder of your server.

Edit : Just download the new version (6.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: just download the last Laragon then

Comment: But now your PHP7 installation wont work anymore