# how to solve this composer error when developing octobercms website ,i am using php 7.4

Tags: php, octobercms

our Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.30.

PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.30.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Either upgrade PHP to version `8.10`, or use an earlier version of OctoberCMS that supports your current PHP version.

Comment: I think this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846653/your-composer-dependencies-require-a-php-version-8-1-0

Comment: can you pelase share your composer.json file, it seems there is something that need PHP 8.0, we need to remove it OR we can make its version lower so it can work with 7.4

Comment: Anything unclear about that error message?

Answer (score 1):

Update your PHP version to 8.1.0 or use an earlier build of octoberCMS that supports php version 7.4.30

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue by changing the following code from vendor/composer/platform_check.php

if (!(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80100)) {
$issues[] = 'Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running ' . PHP_VERSION . '.';
}

To

if (!(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70400)) {
$issues[] = 'Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running ' . PHP_VERSION . '.';
}

Comment: That does not sound like a good idea. That file will be regenerated on the next run of Composer, and there's a good reason that it contains the information you found there: the code of your application is currently not compatible with PHP 7.4

Answer (score -1):

i had the same error, and when i checked php version with "php -v" there didn't seem to be a problem (higher than required and than the version supposedly ran in the error), I then realized that **it was my wamp server** that ran a lower version of php. i didn't have tu upgrade anything it was just a parameters problem. So i changed in two clic the version that my software was running and that was fixed. I hope that will help someone.