# How to fix 2 php on mac

Tags: php, laravel, macos

if I check my laravel version it running php 7.1.33

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.1.33. in /Users/mymac/.composer/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

but when i check my php there is 8.1.12 version

PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 21 2022 12:01:33) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

how can i delete php 7.1.33 or switch to php 8.1.0 ?

Comment: You can try these answers at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846653/your-composer-dependencies-require-a-php-version-8-1-0

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed PHP on your mac.

I've installed php versions using one of the below through brew

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.1
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.2
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.3
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.2
```

Then if I want to change versions (due to different project requirements) I use the below command

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@8.1
```

swapping out the `8.1` for the version that you need.

My information is from [This link here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-multiple-php-versions) and I found it to work well for me

Answer (score -1):

Search 'composer.json' on your laravel folder then you find this :

```
   "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
```

change that version to `"^8.1.0"`

Comment: That has nothing to do with the error, it is saying that the user's PHP version is `7.1`, not that it requires `^7.3`